# overlaying cardwidgets in kotlin/xml (android studio)

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-studio, mobile

I was wondering is there a way to achieve this look in XML. I have tried to achieve something in xml but it still no where near it. I tried for example adding card widgets and laying this attemping to clip but it's almost impossible.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hRYR.png)

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.55"
        android:foregroundTint="#9AB76C"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="25dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp">
            <!-- user info !-->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:ignoreGravity="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">


                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="42sp"
                        android:layout_height="42sp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|left"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_backarrow" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="42sp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|left"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_light"
                        android:includeFontPadding="true"
                        android:padding="2sp"

                        android:text="Settings"
                        android:textColor="#9AB76C"
                        android:textSize="27sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|end"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
                        android:contentDescription="click"
                        android:contextClickable="false"

                        android:foregroundGravity="right"
                        android:minWidth="48dp"
                        android:minHeight="48dp"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/more"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="0.5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="81dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                        android:cropToPadding="false"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/username"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="#9AB76C"
                        android:backgroundTintMode="add"
                        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_light"
                        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
                        android:hint="Username"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textColorHighlight="@color/cardview_dark_background" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/username"

                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:backgroundTint="#9AB76C"
                        android:backgroundTintMode="add"
                        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_light"
                        android:hint="Password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textColorHighlight="@color/cardview_dark_background" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I just wanna know what suggestions there is. since i didn't find any type of z index in android studio

Comment: Can you post an image of what it looks like after you've tried? In XML, items that were added later in the layout are on top, ones added first are on the bottom.